# Is there a keyboard bindable command for reset layout in visual studio 2010 cider designer?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, hotkeys, cider

I'm using the Visual Studio 2010 WPF designer to lay out a window, and the Reset Layout function is proving very useful whenever I move something around as the designer defaults to specifying widths, heights, and massive margins to get it into whichever exact position I have dropped it in, making the automatic layout features of WPF almost useless unless I get rid of those specifications.

At the moment I am accessing this function by right-clicking on the control in question, selecting Reset Layout from the context menu, and then selecting All. As I'm not using any of the other options in here, and I'm using it a lot, I wanted a hotkey, but that's where I'm getting stuck.

I've looked in the Options->Keyboard window, but if there's a command for it there then I can't find it because it's not named unambiguously enough (I've searched for commands including Layout, and commands including Reset, and there's a few that -might- be it, but probably aren't right). I have searched the internet for any hint of a list of designer hotkeys, but what I have found is very limited, and never covered adding new ones.

Does anyone know what this command is called so that I can bind it using the Visual Studio keyboard hotkeys menu? Is it even available?

Alternatively, maybe I'm going about this wrong - is there a way of clearing the layout of a control when moving it around or dropping one from the toolbar that's quicker than putting it roughly where you want and using Reset Layout via the context menu? I *could* just edit the XAML directly, but I have a lot of controls to move around and I find it slower than using the menu.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [record a temporary macro](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7kyhdt1z.aspx), then view the code in the [Macros IDE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tyhxw5y%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), which gives you the command names.

Unfortunately, these commands don't seem to be part of the VS command framework because they are not recorded. They must be internal to the XAML designer.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that myself and saw that they weren't recorded, I wasn't sure whether that meant they didn't exist at all. I guess I'll have to just keep on using the context menu.